# filling a sudoku Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sudoku

I am given a sudoku which is a 9x9 matrix made of 9 3x3 blocks. [Sudoku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku)

Given an integer n and a sudoku S I need to put n into S 9 times such that after putting in n 9 times each block and column contains the value only once.

Task: Count the number of ways n can be put into S 9 times

Given all the empty cells for which n is a possible value I could look at all 9-tuples, but I think checking those would be way too much.

Does anyone know how of a better/more efficient approach/algorithm ?

Comment: I think you are overestimating the number of places you can place a single n. Even on a totally empty board it is only 46656 combinations, and any other filled square reduces this.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö Can you elaborate how you come to 46656 ? First the first time I have 81 possible squares. For the second time 81-16, since I have to ignore the block and row where I put in the first time. Continuing this I get more than what you got

Comment: Think on it in terms of blocks instead. Lets number them 1-9 from top left to bottom right. You need to put your number n in all 9 blocks so lets start with block 1 where you have 9 possibilities. Then continue with block 2 where you have 6 possibilities (your choice in block one blocks 1 row). Then go on to block 3 where two rows are blocked, so only 3 possibilities left. Continue with the next row of blocks where you will have 6, 4 and 2 possibilities. For the last row of blocks you now have 3, 2 and 1 possibility. Total 46656.